# Hide and show when click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have code like this (HTML/CSS/JS):

```js
$('.subnav__right li a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var $this = $(this).parent().find('.subnav__hover');
     $('.subnav__hover').not($this).hide();
     
     $this.toggle();
     
 });

 $(document).mouseup(function (e)
 {
     var container = $('.subnav__hover');

     if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
     {
         container.hide();
     }
 });
```

```css
.subnav__hover{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subnav__right">
  <ul>
    <li class="subnav__notif">
      <a href="#" class="np-ico-notification">Link 1</a>
      <div class="subnav__hover"> CONTENT 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="subnav__caremail">
      <a href="#" class="np-ico-caremail">Link 2</a>
      <div class="subnav__hover"> CONTENT 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="subnav__profile">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <div class="subnav__hover"> CONTENT 3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is toggle function (when I click `.subnav__right li a`) doesn't work. But click the outside can hide `.subnav__hover`.

Any idea how to make the toggle works?

Comment: Jade is less readable, you would better provide HTML.

Comment: @dfsq I changed to code snippet

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Mustaghees here is http://jsfiddle.net/fsoh6h3z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made small changes like change the document event and add `e.stopPropagation()`. Please check.

```js
$('.subnav__right li a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
     var $this = $(this).parent().find('.subnav__hover');
     $('.subnav__hover').not($this).hide();
     
     $this.toggle();
     
 });

 $(document).click(function (e)
 {
     var container = $('.subnav__hover');

     if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
     {
         container.hide();
     }
 });
```

```css
.subnav__hover{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subnav__right">
  <ul>
    <li class="subnav__notif">
      <a href="#" class="np-ico-notification">Link 1</a>
      <div class="subnav__hover"> CONTENT 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="subnav__caremail">
      <a href="#" class="np-ico-caremail">Link 2</a>
      <div class="subnav__hover"> CONTENT 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="subnav__profile">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <div class="subnav__hover"> CONTENT 3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry I back again here.
I have another question, how about I have link on sub menu?
Like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fsoh6h3z/
The link doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, ignore this. Just found the answer :). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
     var container = $('.subnav__hover:visible');
        var clickedObj = $(e.target).next('.subnav__hover');
     if (!container.is(clickedObj) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
     {
         container.hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the click function should be:

```
$('.subnav__right ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.subnav__hover');
    $('.subnav__hover').not($this).hide();

    $this.toggle();
});
```

Comment: Does it makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Bind this to the callback or use that.

```
var that = this;
$('.subnav__right li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(that).parent().find('.subnav__hover');
    $('.subnav__hover').not($this).hide();

    $this.toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing the not `!` operator solves your problem (I guess), so your 2nd part of your JS code will be:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $('.subnav__hover');

    if (container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsoh6h3z/1/

Comment: Unfortunately click outside the area can hide the submenu